# No compiler error when fixed size char array is initialized without enough room for null terminator

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, char, initialization

Suppose I have the following c char arrays:

```
char okaysize4[5] = "four";   // line 5
char toosmall4[4] = "four";   // line 6
char toosmall3[3] = "four";   // line 7
```

When I compile with gcc 4.4.7, I get the following error:

> array.c:7: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long

This error is expected for line 7, as I am trying to stuff 5 chars `("four" + \0)` into a 3 element array.
Also no error is expected for line 5 as the 5 element array is big enough.

However I'm surprised there is no similar error for line 6.  What ends up getting initialized in `toosmall4` is an unterminated string, which can cause all sorts of trouble.

My understanding is that the c string literal `"four"` should be five characters long, due to the null terminator.  In fact `sizeof("four")` is 5.  So why does the compiler not give an error here?

Is there some way I can alter my declaration/definition/initialization so that an error is flagged in this case?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is expected behavior for line 6, from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *14* says (*emphasis mine*):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the
>   character string literal (**including the terminating null character
>   if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

In the C11 draft standard the relevant section with similar wording is `6.7.9` paragraph *14*, and as the [C FAQ says](http://c-faq.com/ansi/nonstrings.html):

> The array is therefore not a true C string and cannot be used with
>   strcpy, printf's %s format, etc.

As Keith Thompson noted, *C++* is stricter, the relevant section in the draft C++ standard says the following:

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [ Example:
>
> ```
> char cv[4] = "asdf"; // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing ’\0’. —end example ]

Comment: This feature has been in C since forever.

Answer (score 5):

It's legal, `toosmall4` is not a string, but a valid char array(without the terminating null character).

Reference: [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/nonstrings.html).