# Strange runtime error, fprintf writes more than asked

Tags: c

I have a runtime error which writes more data from an array than its suppose to print ID, AverageMarks and Status:

Declaration & Its Function

```
char StudentStatus[10][7];

for(x=0;x<10;x++)
{
   fprintf(OutputFile,"%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%s\n",StudentID[x],StudentAvg[x],StudentStatus[x]);
}
```

But when it prints

> 100        77          DismissActive
>   101     85          Active
>   102     88          Active
>   103     86          Active
>   104     85          Active
>   105     84          Active
>   106     84          Active
>   107     82          Active
>   108     92          Active
>   109     75          Dismiss

The way the array was filled:

```
for(x=0;x<NumOfStudent;x++)
{


  if(StudentAvg[x]>80)
  {
     strcpy(StudentStatus[x],"Active");
     printf(". ");
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(StudentStatus[x],"Dismiss");
    printf(". ");
  }
}
```

Other statements works fine but the first statement really troubles me. Any suggestion where I code wrongly?

Comment: This code is not sufficient to spot the error. How do you set the array?

Comment: Are you certain that `StudentStatus[0]` is not set to `DismissActive`?

Comment: Looks like a problem in your `StudenStatus[]` array (maybe a string wasn't zero-terminated).

Comment: Check out this question, and see if you can spot your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694796/no-compiler-error-when-fixed-size-char-array-is-initialized-without-enough-room

Comment: Post more code related to how the StudentStatus array is filled.

Comment: perreal:Well the code it quite long but ok.  Blorgbeard:Yes its DismissActive..

Comment: Thanks everyone for lighting fast response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow for the terminating null, change your array declaration to:

```
char StudentStatus[10][8];
```

C strings are null-terminated, so the string "Dismiss" needs at least 8 bytes of storage.