# Passing not null terminated string to printf results in unexpected value

Tags: c, string, printf

This C program gives a weird result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char str1[5] = "abcde";
   char str2[5] = " haha";

   printf("%s\n", str1);
   return 0;
}
```

when I run this code I get:

```
abcde haha
```

I only want to print the first string as can be seen from the code.
Why does it print both of them?

Comment: Because you limited the length of `str1` to 5, no string terminator was stored as part of the array. Therefore it overflowed on printing into the next string. This is Undefined Behaviour, and may not always happen like this.

Comment: See [No compiler error when fixed size char array is initialized without enough room for null terminator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20694796/1708801)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`"abcde"` is actually 6 bytes long because of the null terminating character in C strings. When you do this:

```
char str1[5] = "abcde";
```

You aren't storing the null terminating character so it is not a proper string.

When you do this:

```
char str1[5] = "abcde";
char str2[5] = " haha";
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

It just happens to be that the second string is stored right after the first, although this is not required.  By calling `printf` on a string that isn't null terminated you have already caused undefined behavior.

Update:

As stated in the comments by clcto this can be avoided by not explicitly specifying the size of the array and letting the compiler determine it based off of the string:

```
char str1[] = "abcde";
```

or use a pointer instead if that works for your use case, although they are not the same:

```
const char *str1 = "abcde";
```

Comment: by ... caused undefined _before_...  did you mean ...caused undefined _behavior_?

Comment: Yes I meant behavior, fingers thinking faster than the brain, Sourav Ghosh's edit is correct and appreciated.

Comment: Suggest using `chr str1[] = "abcde";` to prevent this?

Comment: Or use the more usual `char *str1 = "abcde";`

Answer (score 20):

Both strings `str1` and `str2` are not null terminated. Therefore the statement

```
 printf("%s\n", str1);
```

will invoke undefined behavior.
`printf` prints the characters in a string one by one until it encounters a `'\0'` which is not present in your string. In this case `printf` continues past the end of the string until it finds a null character somewhere in the memory. In your case it seems that `printf` past the end of string `"abcde"` and continues to print the characters from second string `" haha"` which is by chance located just after first string in the memory.

Better to change the block

```
   char str1[5] = "abcde";
   char str2[5] = " haha";
```

to

```
 char str1[] = "abcde";
 char str2[] = " haha";
```

to avoid this problem.

Comment: ..or suffers from segfault of inaccessible memory.

Comment: It can even be seen by doing a `printf("%d", sizeof(str1));` of the second block of strings... `6`

Answer (score 11):

Technically, this behavior is not *unexpected*, it is *undefined*: your code is passing a pointer to a C string that lacks null terminator to `printf`, which is undefined behavior.

In your case, though, it happens that the compiler places two strings back-to-back in memory, so `printf` runs into `null` terminator after printing `str2`, which explains the result that you get.

If you would like to print only the first string, add space for null terminator, like this:

```
char str1[6] = "abcde";
```

Better yet, let the compiler compute the correct size for you:

```
char str1[] = "abcde";
```

Comment: str2 also was not given space for a null character, so is it just a coincidence that nothing more is printed after str2? It could continue reading memory even further?

Comment: It was unexpected by at least one person :)

Answer (score 6):

You have invoked undefined behaviour. Here:

```
   char str1[5] = "abcde";
```

`str1` has space for the above five letters but no null terminator.
Then the way you try to pass not null terminated string to `printf` for printing, invokes undefined behaviour.

In general in most of the cases it is not good idea to pass not null terminated strings to standard functions which expect (C) strings.

Comment: Yeah, looks better, +1.

Answer (score 4):

In C such declarations

```
char str1[5] = "abcde";
```

are allowed. In fact there are 6 initializers because the string literal includes the terminating zero. However in the left side there is declared a character array that has only 5 elements. So it does not include the terminating zero.

It looks like

```
char str1[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '\0' };
```

If you would compile this declaration in C++ then the compiler issues an error.

It would be better to declare the array without specifying explicitly its size.

```
char str1[] = "abcde";
```

In this case it would have the size equal to the number of characters in the string literal including the terminating zero that is equal to 6. And you can write

```
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

Otherwise the function continues to print characters beyond the array until it meets the zero character.

Nevertheless it is not an error. Simply you should correctly specify the format specifier in the call of printf:

```
printf("%5.5s\n", str1);
```

and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Would be so much nicer this answer with just one space added in front of the first 3 code blocks! Such a shame I have to find 6 characters to add to be able to edit it :(

Comment: @PeterSW OK, this one's for you. Happy? ;-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Much better :)

Answer (score -1):

The `%s` specifier searches for a null termination. Therefore you need to add `'\0'` to the end of your string

```
char str1[6] = "abcde\0";
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The compiler will add the terminating `nul` providing there is room for it. If you declare `char str1[] = "abcde\0";` then `sizeof str1` will be 7, not 6, since it will contain **two** `nul`s.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, it is not incorrect, at all!. If you "want" to give the size of the array in the declaration then you *have* to manually add the null termination. Now if you leave the compiler to decided the size of the string for you, then the compiler will add the null termination for you. Therefore you either do `char str1[] = "abcde";` or `char str1[6] = "abcde\0";`. In both cases `sizeof(str1) = 6`

Comment: No, you do *not* need to add `'\0'` to the end of your string. `char str1[6] = "abcde";` is enough. If there is room for it, the compiler will add it. If not, you can't add it manually.