# void pointer as an argument in function

Tags: c

I have a function `f1` which expects void pointer. From the caller I want to have generic logic of passing void pointer to `A` which modifies the pointer internally.

sample code is pasted below :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "malloc.h"
void f1(void* a)
{
    printf("f(a) address = %p \n",a);
    a = (void*)(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("a address = %p \n",a);
    *(int*)a = 3;

    printf("data = %d\n",*(int*)a);
}

void f(void)
{
    void* a1=NULL;
    printf("a1 address = %p \n",a1);

    f1(a1);

    printf("a1 address = %p \n",a1);
    printf("Data.a1 = %d\n",*(int*)a1);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

But it causes segmentation fault. Is there any way to make it work without changing prototype of function `f1`?

Comment: I have seen people casting `void *` to anything like `int *` or `float *` for the return value of `malloc()` but you ... `void *` -> `int *` -> `void *`? Why?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant maybe the same reason [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31010895/2173917) got. ....sigh.... :-|

Answer (score 5):

`C` uses pass-by-value for function argument passing. If you have to change the passed variable itself from inside the function, you need to have a pointer to the variable.

In your case, it should be a pointer to pointer.

Otherwise, after the call to `f1(a1);`, in `f()`, `a` is still `NULL` and dereferencing it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB.

That said,

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. you don't need `#include "malloc.h"` to use `malloc()`, rather use `#include <stdlib.h>`. It is declared in `stdlib.h` header file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the pointer, not the ponted to data. So you must pass a pointer to the pointer, like this

```
void f1(void **a)
 {
    int *b;
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));

    printf("b address = %p \n", b);
    if (b != NULL)
     {
        b[0] = 3;
        printf("data = %d\n", *(int *) b);
     }
    *a = b;
 }
```

The way you do it, the pointer inside `f1` is a copy of the passed pointer, they both contain the same initial value `NULL`, the value you used in `f()` to initialize `a1`, but you alter the value of the local pointer only.

You then dereference `a1` which is still `NULL`, and dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, causes undefined behavior. In your case the behavior is that a segmentation fault happens.